# chrome not allowing localhost origin

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, cors

i have a tomcat server, in web xml i defined cors filter to accept all requests.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

In network inspector in chrome i get report that request arrived successfully, i even can see the response JSON. [network inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsEtH.png)

But in console i still get this error message:
`Failed to load http://localhost:8080/refactor/repair: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

EDIT: just tried opening my web page in internet explorer and there it works fine

Comment: Does it help if you set a domain (something like `project-name.dev`) to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file? Or `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` if you're a windows user.

Comment: thanks for reply, tried your solution but without effect

Comment: apologies, don't know how i missed it, you're right - not sure why then!

Comment: it is a file, to add some info the cors filter worked flawlessly until recently when i installed android studio on my machine, dont know if it is somehow connected.

Comment: Ok, this is expected behaviour for requests from local files. If you have a mac, you can use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081` to serve the file via a server. But you have internet explorer, so you have windows.. let me think for a sec. Turns out, you can run it on windows too :)

Comment: i dont have a mac, but if it actully can help i look into some http server for windows, thanks, ill post my result tomorow

Comment: I just read, that it works on windows too, if you have python below version 3

Comment: On windows: `py -m http.server 8081`

Comment: or `py -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081` (it depends on the python version on your machine)

Comment: well, tried it thru some minimal http server package from npm, and it works !! thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad i could help. I will create a normal answer out of it. would be nice if you accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a page requests an ajax request, but the page itself is not run on via a server, which means it does not have an http protocol, then it will also not have an `origin`. This is mandatory though for the server that receives the ajax requests to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

By using a simple http server e.g. the one that python is shipped with, this could be solved with ease.

For **windows** users with **python 2**:

```
py -m SimpleHTTPServer <SOME_PORT>
```

For **windows** users with **python 3**:

```
py -m http.server <SOME_PORT>
```

For **mac/linux** users with **python 2**:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer <SOME_PORT>
```

For **mac/linux** users with **python 3**:

```
python -m http.server <SOME_PORT>
# or the binary might be python3:
python3 -m http.server <SOME_PORT>
```